# Create an XLS file using something like fputcsv?

Tags: php, excel, csv, xls, xlsx

Is there a lightweight method like below which creates XLS files without prompting for the tab delimiter when opening the file?

```
$list = array (
  array('Cell A1', 'Cell A2'),
  array('Cell B1', 'Cell B2'),
);      

$fp = fopen('file.xls', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Nope.  But Excel can read CSV files, so...

Comment: True, but it prompts for the tab delimiter settings, which the client doesn't know.

Comment: Odd...it doesn't do that for me, as long as the filename has a .CSV extension.  And if you have to have .XLS, then you should actually be generating an Excel file...cause that's what Excel is expecting from that extension.  Just so happens it falls back to "WTF IS THIS" mode when it sees the file is text.

Comment: I see... It just seems a shame to use 20mb for phpExcel when the above code is just a whisker away from making the perfect file!

Comment: The above is not even *close* to making the perfect .XLS file.  In fact, it's so far off that Excel is now looking at you and asking, "Umm, i know absolutely *nothing* about this data.  Can you tell me everything about how to interpret it?".  If you name the file as .CSV, it'd work great.  If you want .XLS, you'll need to rewrite to use a library that generates actual Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Note that the entirety of the PHPExcel library __code__ is 3.71MB, not 20MB... you don't need all the documentation and examples on your website, only the code

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1**

Save you data in an "XML Spreadsheet".

Since Microsoft Excel version 2002 and higher, you can open and save Excel documents in the "XML Spreadsheet" format. Those files are Excel documents saved with an XML source instead of a binary source. Such Excel documents saved in XML enable nearly all worksheets features (makeup, formats, formulas) but Graphics and Visual Basic Macros are not supported (all differences are documented [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/features-and-limitations-of-xml-spreadsheet-format-in-excel-HA001034639.aspx?redir=0)).

**Solution #2**

Use [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) to easily build an XLSX file.
OpenTBS is a small PHP tool that can easily build an XLSX file using the technique of templates. OpenTBS templates can be entirely designed with Ms Excel.